# Parameters aren't showing up under Dataset Panel SSRS 2005

Tags: parameters, visual-studio-2005

Working with a report in Visual Studio 2005, I am facing a weird issue.  I am not seeing parameters under Datasets panel.  I added additional parameters in my procedure and was expecting to change its type to date, etc under parameter properties.  This is going on with every single report.  Is there a way to fix it?  I tried going through several items and shortcuts (example:  ctr + alt + D) under View, but couldn't figure out how to display the report parameters.

[image: Image:]

Answer (score 0):

We just upgraded to a newer version of Visual Studio and it solved the problem.  Couldn't figure out any other way.